Prisoners given dark glasses at the end so the sun wouldn't hurt their eyes
There was an English-language movie that I saw on TV in the 70's or 80's.  I don't know how old it was but it seemed to have been made somewhere between 1965 and 1980. The only element I remember is that people who had been held prisoner (underground in a large prison or insane asylum) were going to be released, in the last 1/2 hour of the movie. The protagonist got a bunch of sunglasses for them so that when they came out, the sun wouldn't blind them.
Does that movie ring a bell for anyone?

Possibly Brubaker from 1980 with Robert Redford and Yaphet Kotto:

The new warden of a small prison farm in Arkansas tries to clean it up of corruption after initially posing as an inmate.

This scene is discussed in a review:

Brubaker gets his staff to release a few long term solitary confinements, stating that before they do so, the requisite pairs of sunglasses should be given to them as they come out of complete darkness for the first time in ages

Here's the trailer:




I'm not sure that's it, but the sunglasses reference fits perfectly so I'll mark this as The Answer. Thanks! :)
